# clone a JVM with POSIX fork through JNI, but child JVM will not exit

Tags: java, linux, java-native-interface, fork

I'm trying to clone a running JVM with POSIX fork. The way I get access to fork is through JNI (i.e. https://github.com/kohsuke/akuma/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sun/akuma/CLibrary.java). After the fork, I'd like both the parent and the child to do some computation and then exit.

The following is the test code. After the fork, I can see two lines of "After the fork.", meaning that both the parent and the child reach this point. But then, the parent process exits normally while the child process doesn't.

Furthermore, I cannot kill the child process with signal 15 in the terminal. I have to use kill -9 to kill the child JVM process.

Any idea of what might be wrong?

```
import static com.sun.akuma.CLibrary.LIBC;

public class ForkTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int pid = LIBC.fork();
        if (pid == 0) {
            System.out.println("This is the child.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("This is the parent. child pid=" + pid);
        }
        System.out.println("After the fork.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely; The JVM wasn't designed to be used this way and so it doesn't work.  Why not use multiple threads?

Comment: Perhaps you need some work to do catching or supressing signals - for example SIGCHLD

Comment: @PeterLawrey thread is not suitable for what I'd like to achieve. I basically would like to create a snapshot of a JVM, and later may revert to this snapshot. One clean way to implement this is through fork. I first fork the parent JVM, let the parent wait at this moment and let the child JVM proceed to do the work. If the later, the child decides to revert, it just terminates itself and let the parent JVM resume execution from the point where the snapshot is taken. I'm writing a java library for this and it has to be application agnostic. So thread is not quite what I want.

Comment: @Ingo Thank you for pointing me to this direction. Could you please shed more light on this?

Comment: While it would be cool if it worked, most Java developers would consider this a hack.  The JVM is a complex application and I suspect there is any number things which don't work properly using this approach, e.g. say one fork modifies a file which is open or reads from a Socket.

Comment: @Awaken, well, it's quite some time since I did this stuff, but (in Unix) a dying child may cause the parent to get a SIGCHLD signal. Depending on the current signal settings, this could be ignored, or send the JVM to some signal handler code. I am not sure what happens when the parent dies first. I guess the JVM will do some signal handling on its own and will probably get a bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

@Awaken
According to this article http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them, when you fork a multithreaded application only the thread that called fork() stays alive while other threads die. I don't think you can accomplish the snapshot in the child if you lose all threads.

Answer (score 0):

you must kill process in else Statement like this

```
else {
System.out.println("This is the parent. child pid=" + pid);
LIBC.kill(pid, 9);
}
```