# How can I fork a child process which contains the same program as the Parent process in Java

Tags: java, processbuilder

How can I fork a child process which contains the same program as the Parent process in Java. I have used ProcessBuilder but the problem is there is no way to have a section of code which is only run by child process as we can do by unix fork() system call. Please help.

Comment: please put in some code snippets in your question.

Comment: You may need JNI. Even then result may not be that great. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735660/clone-a-jvm-with-posix-fork-through-jni-but-child-jvm-will-not-exit

Comment: You could make the parent process bind to a port... When the child process starts up it would attempt to bind to the same port, and fail. Now you know its a child process. This serves as a global mutex.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have a `fork()` equivalent.  It wouldn't make much sense.  If you need parallel execution *and* shared memory then you should use threads instead.  If you just need to run the same Java program in parallel without shared memory then either threads or a separate process (via `ProcessBuilder`) could work.

Comment: I need shared memory for communication between child and parent. Child will basically send a signal to the parent notifying parent to exit.

Comment: For shared memory, everything needs to run in the same JVM.  As I said, that means threads for parallelism, not processes.

Comment: Note, too, that even with a C program, `fork()` *duplicates* memory but does not itself provide *shared* memory.